# compare password between form and database is invalid always

Tags: python, django, mongodb, bcrypt

Im trying to create a login system with Python/Django/MongoDB.

This is my code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from pymongo import MongoClient
import bcrypt

def login( req ):
    response = { 'error': 'Error' }

    if req.POST['username'] and req.POST['password']:
        u = req.POST['username']
        p = req.POST['password'].encode('utf8')

        client = MongoClient()
        result = client['db']['users'].find_one({'name': u})
        if result:
            hashed = bcrypt.hashpw( result['password'].encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt() )

            if bcrypt.checkpw( p, hashed ):
                response = { 'error': 'Welcome!' }
            else:
                response = { 'error': 'Invalid password' }
        else:
            response = { 'error': 'Invalid username' }
    else:
        response = { 'error': 'Password/Username empty' }

    return render( req, 'crawler/login.html', response )
```

How must I use `bcrypt.checkpw()`

I Stored the password like this `$2b$12$tapbosJdMHGCnO6zb.n7Wu3acXyBh4Cj2jdJGv.1TmMBWYtd.nnWW` and the test real password is `'password'` How must I store the passwords? How must I compare the passwords? (From DB against Form incoming values)

Thank you for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

Your method is very complicated, you can easily do like this :

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

Comment: It is not related to django admin. It's a simple view

Comment: Thanks, but I can´t see Mongo´s connection, and I don´t undestrand how you code works :S